# how to set specific text to dropdown when i select a dropdown value in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a drop-down in asp.net core with country name and code. i need, when i select a drop-down value than it should be set a only code in drop-down. I have a screenshot you can see that,

> [screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOgi.png)
>
> now i have a second screen shot i want to like this drop-down after select value.
>   [second Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvbb8.png)
>
> my view drop-down code is

```
    <select class="form-control" id="countryDropdown" >
    @foreach (var country in Model)
    {
        <option value="@country.id"
                data-code="@country.codeName">
            @country.Name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

html dropdown is

```
<select class="form-control" id="countryDropdown">
        <option value="3" data-code="93">
            Afghanistan (93)
        </option>
        <option value="264" data-code="">
            Åland Islands ()
        </option>
        <option value="4" data-code="355">
            Albania (355)
        </option>
        <option value="5" data-code="213">
            Algeria (213)
        </option>
        <option value="6" data-code="1">
            American Samoa (1)
        </option>
        <option value="7" data-code="376">
            Andorra (376)
        </option>
        <option value="8" data-code="244">
            Angola (244)
        </option>
        <option value="9" data-code="1">
            Anguilla (1)
        </option>
        <option value="266" data-code="">
            Anonymous Proxy ()
        </option>
        <option value="10" data-code="672">
            Antarctica (672)
        </option>
        <option value="11" data-code="1">
            Antigua and Barbuda (1)
        </option>
        <option value="12" data-code="54">
            Argentina (54)
        </option>
        <option value="13" data-code="374">
            Armenia (374)
        </option>
        <option value="14" data-code="297">
            Aruba (297)
        </option>
        <option value="268" data-code="">
            Asia/Pacific Region ()
        </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Edit your question and put your view code.

Comment: i update a code now you can see that

Comment: I need the other field beside it as well. Thanks.

Comment: i am getting a data from database.you can try with static data

Comment: now i update A  question i hope its helpful for you

Comment: i have a only dropdown field now i again update a code with html

Comment: I added an answer, just copy and paste the script, I made it exactly for your dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, we're wrapping the Country text inside a span tag. Whenever we click on the dropdown, this would fill the span tag with Country property. When you're done choosing an option, this would empty the span tag.

**Add this to your script;**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#countryDropdown").find("option").each(function() {
    var codeIndex = $(this).text().indexOf("(");
    var country = $(this).text().substring(0, codeIndex);
    var code = $(this).text().substring(codeIndex);
    $(this).html("<span class='select-hide' data-country='" + country + "'></span>" + code);
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").focus(function() {
    $(this).find(".select-hide").each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).data("country"));
    });
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").change(function() {
    $(this).blur();
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").blur(function() {
    $(this).find(".select-hide").each(function() {
      $(this).text("");
    });
  });
});
```

---

**Demo below;**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#countryDropdown").find("option").each(function() {
    var codeIndex = $(this).text().indexOf("(");
    var country = $(this).text().substring(0, codeIndex);
    var code = $(this).text().substring(codeIndex);
    $(this).html("<span class='select-hide' data-country='" + country + "'></span>" + code);
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").focus(function() {
    $(this).find(".select-hide").each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).data("country"));
    });
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").change(function() {
    $(this).blur();
  });

  $("#countryDropdown").blur(function() {
    $(this).find(".select-hide").each(function() {
      $(this).text("");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="countryDropdown">
  <option value="3" data-code="93">
    Afghanistan (93)
  </option>
  <option value="264" data-code="">
    Åland Islands ()
  </option>
  <option value="4" data-code="355">
    Albania (355)
  </option>
  <option value="5" data-code="213">
    Algeria (213)
  </option>
  <option value="6" data-code="1">
    American Samoa (1)
  </option>
  <option value="7" data-code="376">
    Andorra (376)
  </option>
  <option value="8" data-code="244">
    Angola (244)
  </option>
  <option value="9" data-code="1">
    Anguilla (1)
  </option>
  <option value="266" data-code="">
    Anonymous Proxy ()
  </option>
  <option value="10" data-code="672">
    Antarctica (672)
  </option>
  <option value="11" data-code="1">
    Antigua and Barbuda (1)
  </option>
  <option value="12" data-code="54">
    Argentina (54)
  </option>
  <option value="13" data-code="374">
    Armenia (374)
  </option>
  <option value="14" data-code="297">
    Aruba (297)
  </option>
  <option value="268" data-code="">
    Asia/Pacific Region ()
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Jishan's answer is good too, it's only changing the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this.

This very simple and easy to understand and faster.

Please check this link [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9q51sj2/)

Note: please uncomment the console.log for more detail.

and You can modify this code as per your requirement here I'm sowing the current data-code display in the dropdown option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#countryDropdown option:first").text($("#countryDropdown option:first").data("code"));
  $("#countryDropdown").change(function(event) 
  {
     var oCurrentOption =this.options[event.target.selectedIndex];
     $("#countryDropdown option[value="+oCurrentOption.value+"]").text($(oCurrentOption).data("code"));
     //console.log(oCurrentOption);
     //console.log("Data Code "+$(oCurrentOption).data("code"));
     //console.log("Current Text "+oCurrentOption.text);
     //console.log("Current Value "+oCurrentOption.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="countryDropdown">
        <option value="3" data-code="93">
            Afghanistan (93)
        </option>
        <option value="264" data-code="">
            Åland Islands ()
        </option>
        <option value="4" data-code="355">
            Albania (355)
        </option>
        <option value="5" data-code="213">
            Algeria (213)
        </option>
        <option value="6" data-code="1">
            American Samoa (1)
        </option>
        <option value="7" data-code="376">
            Andorra (376)
        </option>
        <option value="8" data-code="244">
            Angola (244)
        </option>
        <option value="9" data-code="1">
            Anguilla (1)
        </option>
        <option value="266" data-code="">
            Anonymous Proxy ()
        </option>
        <option value="10" data-code="672">
            Antarctica (672)
        </option>
        <option value="11" data-code="1">
            Antigua and Barbuda (1)
        </option>
        <option value="12" data-code="54">
            Argentina (54)
        </option>
        <option value="13" data-code="374">
            Armenia (374)
        </option>
        <option value="14" data-code="297">
            Aruba (297)
        </option>
        <option value="268" data-code="">
            Asia/Pacific Region ()
        </option>
</select>
```